# Regex function clarification

Tags: regex

I have a string and I have to filter the following:

```
"#Subject = \"@hb\" + @uv_EmployeeID + \" fdsaas\" + @test"
```

I have to filter only `@uv_EmployeeID` and `@test` and not the values inside ""-inner double quotes

Comment: I doubt all the language tags you spammed are relevant to your problem. I'd recommend to add the one programming language you are actually using.

Comment: C# is the proggraming lang

Comment: The ultimate goal is to get the string that starts with @ but it should not be within double quotes

Answer (score -1):

This is working : `new Regex(@"[^""]@{1}[a-zA-Z_]+");`

You just have to remove the first character from the result, like this :

```
var reg = new Regex(@"[^""]@{1}[a-zA-Z_]+");

var matches = reg.Matches("#Subject = \"@hb\" + @uv_EmployeeID + \" fdsaas\" + @test");

var empId = matches[0].Value.Substring(1); // @uv_EmployeeID
var test = matches[1].Value.Substring(1); // @test
```

Comment: is there any possible way to get the matches without @ in front

Comment: @VIGNESHRK Yes just do a Substring(2) instead of 1, you will skip the 2 first char

Comment: While doing the regex testing, i can find that strings with 2-@'s are also getting matched. For example : @@uv_employee is also getting matched.. For our requirement, we want matched words with only one @ in front of the string. Please help in this.

Comment: Will there always be a space before @ and then a word with only lowercase / uppercase letters and / or _ ? If yes this will do the job : @" @{1}[a-zA-Z_]+"